Pinsker formula
Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces and let $T : X \rightarrow X $, $S : Y \rightarrow  Y $, and $ \pi : X \rightarrow Y $ be continuous maps such that $ \pi $ is surjective and
$$
\pi\circ T = S \circ \pi.
$$
In other words, $ (Y,S) $ is (topologically) a factor of $(X, T)$ by the map $ \pi $. If $ \mu $ is a $T $-invariant probability on $X$ and $h_{\mu}(T)$ denotes the measure-theoretic entropy of $ T $ with respect to $ \mu $, then a formula of Pinsker implies that
$$
h_{\mu}(T) - h_{\mu\circ \pi^{-1}}(S) = h_{\mu}(T|S)
$$
where $h_{\mu}(T|S)$ is the relative metric entropy.
Who can tell me how this formula is proven? Or where I can find the references for this proof?

A proof is given in this paper by Bogenschütz and Crauel: https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0097526

Thank you very much, this is exactly the reference I needed
